# Can i use legend.click_policy="hide" to hide single line in multi_line plot from bokeh?

Tags: python, hide, bokeh, legend

I want to hide certain line in the multi_line plot, but when i add click_policy, it will hide all lines in the figure, is there any way to do it ?
btw, i prefer to use fig.multi_line but fig.line to plot

thanks

```
    fig=figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="",sizing_mode="scale_both",x_axis_type="datetime")
    data_columns = list(source.data.keys())
    fig.multi_line('xs', 'ys', color = 'color', legend_field = 'label', line_width = 3,source = source)
    fig.legend.click_policy="hide"
```

Answer (score 0):

`multi_line` is a single glyph. If it's hidden, it's hidden wholly. I'm afraid you will have to use `line` if you want to work with separate lines.